# How to make Ubuntu 12.04 Server bootable again?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, server, grub2

I just began taking a Digital Forensics course on campus, and thought having Kali Linux would be a good tool to familiarize myself. My computer has two separate hard drives, one for Ubuntu Server 12.04 (home VoIP and sandbox) and the other for Kali. However, upon finishing the install, the grub was installed to the MBR of the first hard drive (the one housing Ubuntu). Now when I boot up the machine, the grub only shows Kali Linux (aside from the Kali recovery mode, memtest, etc)

Any help on getting Ubuntu server bootable again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar if Kali Linux is using grub2, but try to edit the /boot/grub/grub.cfg after booting up your Kali Linux. (older version of grub using /boot/grub/menu.lst as far as i could remember) . Adding the following menuentry to chainload your original bootloader in your 1st hard driver.

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 12.04 Boot' {
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

root should point to where your /boot (if not separated, /) filesystem of your Ubuntu 12.04 server locates. (hd0,1) means first hard drive, 1st partition. Adjust it to fit your actual partitioning case.

P.S.: a little bootstrap background:

your case before change

> BIOS -> first hard driver -> MBR -> active partition (Ubuntu parition) -> grub installed in Ubuntu

after change

> BIOS-> first hard driver -> MBR -> active partition (Kali parition) -> grub installed in Kali

Comment: Funny enough, I was editing my /etc/default/grub to get a better console resolution, and upon entering the update-grub, it generated a new grub.cfg which immediately picked up on my Ubuntu Server partition. Bonehead moment for me. Thanks :-P